# Captioning `qtree` trees

Tags: floats, captions, tikz-qtree, qtree, newfloat

I want to have two trees aligned side by side within a footnote, both captioned and labeled. The following reports an error and produces misalignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

     Sample text.\footnote{Here we have two trees:
     \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}    
     \centering
     \Tree [.S [.NP ] [.VP ] ]     
     \caption{Tree 1}
     \label{label1}
     \end{minipage}

     \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
     \centering

     \Tree [.S [.NP ] [.VP ] ]
     \caption{Tree 2}
     \label{label2}
     \end{minipage}

         }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understand your question (put trees side-by-side), you need firs remove empty line between `minipage`s and than use `\captionof{figure}{...}` for captions:

[image]

(red lines show page layout)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{qtree}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

     Sample text.\footnote{Here we have two trees:
\begin{center}  % <---
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize} % <---
     \begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\linewidth}
     \centering
     \Tree [.S [.NP ] [.VP ] ]
     \captionof{figure}{Tree 1} % <---
     \label{label1}
     \end{minipage}
\hfil     % <---
     \begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\linewidth}
     \centering
     \Tree [.S [.NP ] [.VP ] ]
     \captionof{figure}{Tree 2} % <---
     \label{label2}
     \end{minipage}
\end{center} % <---
         }
\end{document}
```

With `% <---` are marked lines of in MWE which differ from yours MWE.

If this is not the case, what you like to get, please clarify your question.

**Edit**: Added is `captionsetup` for caption of images in footnote. It define font size equal to font size of footnotes.

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the caption font so that it's not larger than the text font?

Comment: @bozidarka, yes it is possible. I added local caption settings (in original answer was fonts accommodated to main text font size), which accommodate caption's font size to footnotes..

Answer (score 1):

What about doing so?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

     Sample text.\footnote{Here we have two trees:\\\\
     \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
     \centering
     Tree 1\\
     \Tree [.S [.NP ] [.VP ] ]
     \label{label1}
     \end{minipage}
~
     \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
     \centering
     Tree 2\\
     \Tree [.S [.NP ] [.VP ] ]
     \label{label2}
     \end{minipage}

         }
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I try to compile that I also get scrambled alignment.

Comment: I updated the LaTeX input. Would this be more sufficient?